# Cooling IAUC90N10S5N062 MOSFET from the top

Tags: mosfet, pcb, buck, heatsink, cooling

I design a sync - buck converter, and I need to cool down my top side and bottom side MOSFETs. For mechanical reasons, it is easier for me to place a heat sink on top of plastic housing of MOSFETs (IAUC90N10S5N062) instead on the bottom side of the PCB. The junction to case resistance of this MOSFET is 1.8 K/W.

Is it good to do this, or is it not worth it doing?

Answer (score 5):

I saw someone tested the thermal resistance though the plastic, and it's not worth it.

Consider a MOSFET made for the purpose such as FDMS86101DC which has a thermal pad on both top and bottom of the capsule.
[image: Dualcool capsule from the datasheet]

Alternatively, there are heatsinks available to fit over an SMD transistor and solder to the PCB where the heatsink area is.

[image]

Image from: https://itecnotes.com/electrical/electronic-how-should-i-design-a-heat-sink-for-an-smd-power-mosfet/

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is spreading out heat laterally, using pours/polygons attached to the devices, and sinking heat vertically using a gap pad.

Multilayer PCB can also be used, to sink heat to the nearest plane layer, spread out, and so on.

Example:

[image: Layout view]

Now, this board happens to have tons of inner planes, so, heat spreading was an absolute non-issue, and... also rather a pain to solder on.  But a 4-layer board with 1-2 oz. inner layers does very well itself.

Q201-Q206 have wide pours to spread out heat, carry current, and minimize inductance.

[image: Top photo]

A heatsink is applied like so:

[image: Heatsink applied]

Low-durometer gap pad fills the spaces between components, contacting the copper pours and board generally.  Due to inner planes, even components not dissipating power directly, can pass some heat to the heatsink this way.

Although the DFN3030 MOSFETs are thinner, they're also smaller, so don't sink much power out of their bodies directly; thermal pours do most of the work here.

Comment: This is a good answer - perhaps it is worth specifying that in order to dissipate the heat that we spread laterally, the copper pour must be on top or bottom layer. At least in my experience, FR4 or equivalent is a rather poor thermal conductor and using (just) an internal layer for heat dissipation usually is not enough. Perhaps you already say this above but to me it does not seem super clear.

Comment: The thickness of FR-4 from outer to inner layers is usually quite small (common proto services offer 5-10 mils), so that its thermal resistance compared to a (more conductive, but much thicker) gap pad, or to the convection constant (if dissipating to air directly), is relatively small. Thermal vias are valuable, of course, and they can be seen in the layout view.